# LESS dynamically create variable names from mixin

Tags: variables, less, mixins

Hi I'm thinking if is possible to automate the process of creation variable names in less?

eg. At the moment I have to write:

```
@list-description-font-color: #000;
@list-description-border-color: #aaa;
@list-description-background-color: #bbb;
@list-description-border-width: #ccc;
```

Will be better if I could define in one place @list-description and than re-use. eg.

```
.list-description(@pre: 'list-description') {

@pre-font-color: #000;
@pre-border-color: #aaa;
@pre-background-color: #bbb;
@pre-border-width: #ccc;

}
```

Even better if I could have an array off extensions eg.

```
@ext: fc font-color, bc border-color, bgc background-color, bw border-width;

    .list-desc(@pre: 'list-description') {

    @pre-@ext{fc}: #000;
    @pre-@ext{bc}: #aaa;
    @pre-@ext{bgc}: #bbb;
    @pre-@ext{bw}: #ccc;

    }
```

And this will generate the original output.

Thanks

Comment: No, you can't dynamically create variables.

Comment: I think we can: http://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-names

Comment: If you see that document clearly, you'd note that they are not exactly *creating* variables, they are evaluating already created variables to assign value to a property. If that is what you are looking at then I can give you a way.

Comment: In general see [#2702](https://github.com/less/less.js/issues/2702) . For your specific use-case/snippet above it's clear you're just about to use variable names to emulate namespaces (thus it's an XY problem, i.e. use namespaces instead of emulating them via global variables).